# sharing dictionary data between callbacks in plotly-dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'd like to share dictionary data between callbacks. so I am using dcc.Store() from below tutorial

https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks

However I got an error of AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_json'. so it looks like I cannot use to_json with dictionary data.

```
@app.callback(
    [
    Output("well-table", "data"),
    Output('stored-shared-data-time-dict','data'),
    Output('stored-shared-data-prod-trajectory-dict','data'),
    Output('stored-shared-data-cross-section-list','data'),  
    Output('stored-shared-data-conformance-trajectory-dict','data'),
    ],
    [
    Input('load-area-data','n_clicks'),
    ],
    [
     State("select-area-dropdown", "value"),
     State('read-existing-data-radio','value'),
    ],
)

def change_area_data(n_clicks,area,read_existing_radio):

...
    return (datatable_thisarea,
            df_timedata_dict.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split'),
            df_prod_trajectory_dict.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split'),
            df_cross_section_dict_list.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split'),
            df_conformance_trajectory_dict.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split'),
           )

     52 
     53     return (datatable_thisarea,
---> 54             df_timedata_dict.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split'),
        df_timedata_dict.to_json = undefined
        global date_format = undefined
        global orient = undefined
     55             df_prod_trajectory_dict.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split'),
     56             df_cross_section_dict_list.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split'),

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_json
```

In the above website, it did mention:

Example 1 - Storing Data in the Browser with dcc.Store
To save data in the user's browser's session:

The data has to be converted to a string like JSON or base64 encoded binary data for storage

so I change to_json to use base64 encode, then I got another error of TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'.

```
import base64

def change_area_data(n_clicks,area,read_existing_radio):

...
    return (datatable_thisarea,
            base64.b64encode(df_timedata_dict), 
            base64.b64encode(df_prod_trajectory_dict),  
            base64.b64encode(df_cross_section_dict_list),  
            base64.b64encode(df_conformance_trajectory_dict) 
           )

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'
```

so so how to share the dictionary data between callback?  I have to use dictionary which contains lots of dataframe with keys. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To convert the python dictionary to json, try using:

```py
import json
json.dumps(name_of_dictionary)
```

Storing data with `dcc.Store` should then function as intended.

Comment: Thank you so much c_48. Yes I just use json.dumps(), then I got another error of TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable.  the dictionary contains dataframe for each key, for example, dict_df={'key1': df1,'key2':df2,'key3':df3}, then I use json.dumps(dict_df). Thanks for help

Comment: Hi c_48,  I got no error when I directly output dictionary to dcc.Store() without using json.dumps(), however when I load the data from dcc.Store() using json.loads(), I got another error of TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType. It looks like it is empty in dcc.store(), how do I check if data in dcc.Store() is not empty? Thanks

Comment: Because the values in your dictionary are dataframes you will likely need to convert each of them separately. This is probably worth a separate question (I see you posted one). I think a good place to start would be checking each of your dataframe variables and each of your dictionary variables, and ensuring these are in fact the format you intend. For example you have a variable `df_prod_trajectory_dict`, which I am not able to tell is a df or a dictionary, so this may be causing some confusion as well.

Comment: yes c_48, I decided to loop over each key in the dictionary and convert each dataframe into json by doing like df.to_json(). I will see how it goes. Thanks